# nodejs googleapis and google-spreadsheet errors

Tags: google-sheets, google-auth-library

Spent several days troubleshooting. No luck. At the end of my wits here.

I have a form on a ReactJS/Vite website. I want data in form to write to Google Sheets after form submission.

I've used the "googleapis" npm package successfully as a nodejs app before. But, this is my first time using it in a reactjs/vite website.

When I import the module,

```
import { google } from "googleapis";
```

my website fails to load and I get bellow error in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnGSF.png)
If I delete this import statement, my website runs fine.

I tried switching to "google-spreadsheet" node package. No error. But this package requires I use "google-auth-library" package. When I import,

```
import { JWT } from "google-auth-library";
```

my website fails to load and I get bellow error in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeqSk.png)

I tried googling everything. I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.